# Any downsides of preferring wildcards *, ? over %, _?

Tags: forms, search, conventions

In my database application I'm intending to give the users simple [glob pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) search possibility besides standard search of text literal. (Let's not mention other search options to keep this question simple.)

They will be able to use wildcards `*`, `?` and `[`...`]` for character matching. `Jo*n` will match `John`, `Jon` or `Johann`. Such an entered pattern will be converted to [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for T-SQL queries, to [RLIKE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp/) in MariaDB queries and to [VB.NET Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) or [C# LikeString() invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145471/2392157) for in-memory search.

**Is it OK to lead users to get familiar with wildcard characters `*` and `?` if these (used in SQL-89) were abandoned since SQL-92 standard in favor of `%` and `_`?.**

Honestly, I think that for non-advanced users, `*` and `?` suit better than `%` and `_` because:

- users know them from OS file masks
- they appear in data less often than `%` and `_`, so there is lesser need to deal with escaping them
- they are better indicating their wildcard nature than `%` and `_` which are a bit ambiguous (`50%` can confuse inexperienced users to think it is a literal)
- they are somewhat easier to type because `*` is directly available at key <kbd>*</kbd> on numeric pad, while all others need pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Are there any real reasons why I should favorize `%` and `_`? If SQL-92 switched to them, perhaps they had some reasons.

Comment: When you say they were abandoned, do you mean it's now invalid, or does it still function (properly) but people just don't like using it?

Comment: @Majo0od - it means it is now invalid. `*` and `?` are now treated as regular characters except of some non-standard database engines like Jet which powers Microsoft Access.

Comment: Then leading them to use it shouldn't be allowed. You shouldn't create a learned behavior that gets the user no where.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't get the point. During searching, users are normally not dealing with SQL as you are not dealing with Google internals during searching. So here I'm addressing the surface, not implementation deep inside.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you meant when it comes to search, that if they should use `*` or `?` while searching. If those options aren't going to do anything, then why should those be used?

Comment: On the front end (user searching - not DB)

Comment: On the font end, I can learn users either `*`+`?` or `%`+`_` (one of these pairs). I can choose any because I **must** transcode it either. Internally, SQL search uses `%`+`_` and in-memory Like operator uses `*`+`?`. Some devs are learning users one set, some the other. I needed to decide and I was consulting my decision in this question from UX perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your interface?

Are users entering SQL `SELECT` statements directly?  If so, you should use `%` and `_` because they're part of the SQL standard, and the user is expecting standard SQL.

Are users entering search terms into an application, which is incidentally using an SQL database as its search backend?  In this case, use `*` and `?` as your wildcards, because that's what they're used to from other applications.

Comment: I agree with you point and moreover, I think that most of users of SQL are at technical level where they already have some experience with glob wildcards, because path to programming including SQL typically goes through other computer basics first.

Answer (score 4):

Are your users more familiar with SQL syntax or search engine syntax? If there's a strong leaning one way or the other, there's your answer.

Comment: Minimum of users is familiar with SQL syntax. Most of users are either standard office folks, some are managers, then designers, engineers, or even workers using their PC's at production lines. It is small ERP actually.

Comment: @miroxlav well, I'd say there's your answer then. Don't worry about the SQL syntax at all. It's not relevant to this user base.

Comment: Thank you very much for leading me to the answer. I wish I could mark two answers! At least I'm giving you credit and upvote. :)

Comment: @miroxlav glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

As for why SQL changed?
This is just my guess

```
select *  
  from table
```

The * means all columns and they did not want to use * for two things

Second I think you would search for a literal * more often than %

Let's say you pick % for the wildcard
If they enter a * then display a warning message
Reminder in  *productname* % is the wildcard - not *
or if the enter ?
Reminder in  *productname* _ is the wildcard - not ?

If you are going to pick * ? then just reverse the reminders

If you are going to get really fancy color up the wild cards as they enter them

I have product that went into a new business space and that space was used to * ? and the product used % _.  Rather than split the product we went with the warning messages,

Comment: They already use `*` for two things: it's also used for multiplication. Like, I believe even in standard SQL, `%` is also a remainder operator. (It definitely is in MS T-SQL, which is the dialect I work with the most.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling OK then they want to use * for less things.  Either way need to deal with there does not appear to single standard here.

Comment: Thank you for the answering the secondary question. After posting it, I tried to post it [as standalone question on programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/271971/any-reasons-why-sql-92-changed-into).

Comment: Come on down vote.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

Some general computer-literate folks would assume `*` and `?` and database-literate folks would assume `%` and `_` and the general public would assume the computer is smart enough to read your mind and that you don't need a trailing wildcard to match.

So, here is where on-screen help text (always visible) is needed.

```
Last Name _________    (Use % to match zero or more characters, _ to match one character)
                       (Sm%th matches Smth, Smyth, Smith but not Smythe)
```

Comment: Good point, hints should never be at last place! There is not much screen estate left in our case, but perhaps field can be decorated with something like different background color or blue corner. Help can pop-up until users mark `[x] do not show me again` etc...